# Does Fisher Information quantify precision?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation, measurement, fisher-information

Looking at perspective from estimating the actual value from a set of data measured by the instrument. Does Fisher information just quantify the precision of the measurement?

What does it say about the "Sensitivity" of the measurement. If it does not address Sensitivity, is there any other quantity which does?

I am Physicist by the upbringing, hence pardon me if I make mistake.

Comment: @Frans Rodenburg Thank You. However, the second part of my question which is about its' relation to sensitivity is not addressed in the answers above. I think this is not exact duplicate of the question suggested.

Comment: Welcome to CV. As you can see in the related question, Fisher information says something about your *parameters*, not your measurements. It therefore has no relationship with the precision of a measurements.

Comment: It is related to precision of measurements (sorry if I am mistaken). There a whole branch of study called Optimal design of experiments.